# AJAX and CI4 returning 500 OR NULL

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am having a unique issue; I have 3 AJAX calls throughout my code that all work TOTALLY fine connecting to Plaid and handling database values. Then I have 1 that WAS returning 200 and the result was NULL -- NOW it is returning a 500 error and saying there is a server issue. I just need to send some data off to calculate something and return it, and I almost have no hair left. Below is my code:

**AJAX Call:**

```
$('#calculateDebtPayoff').on('click', function() {
    
    var owed = $("#dpoOwed").val();
    var int = $('#dpoInterest').val();
    var pymt = $('#dpoPayment').val();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/calculateLoanPayoff',
        data: {owed: owed, interest: int, payments: pymt},
        success: function(result) {
            var response = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log('Error!: ' + result);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP Script:**

```
public function calculateLoanPayoff()
{
    $response = [];
    $months_left = 0;
    
    $owed = $this->request->getVar('owed');
    $interest = $this->request->getVar('interest');
    $payments = $this->request->getVar('payments');
    
    // Numner of Payments = (-log(1 - interest * remaining / payments)) / log(1 + interest)
    $months_left = (-log(1 - $interest * $owed / $payments)) / log(1 + $interest);
    
    $response['months_min'] = $months_left;
    // OTHER VALUES WILL BE ADDED TO THE RESPONSE ARRAY AFTER I NAIL THIS THING
    
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

**Routes:**

```
$routes->post('calculateLoanPayoff', 'DreamsCalculators::calculateLoanPayoff');
```

About 30 minutes ago, the `success` function of the call was returning `200` but the result was NULL; 5 minutes ago, it all started returning `500`.

I have tried:

```
1. Using dataType: "json"
2. Using url: "<?= base_url(Class/method); ?>"
3. Passing headers: {'Content-Type: ', etc.}
4. My data is returned in PHP json_encode($response)
5. Tried contentType: false and dataType: false
```

At this point, I don't care if the Math is wrong or right, I just want something to return and for it to be some kind of data I am looking for. I know it's not the `url` cause I have 3 others that I structured the same way and they all work.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: I think you have defined the variable as "payment" in ajax but calling as "payments" in   $payments = $this->request->getVar('payments');

Comment: @ManashreeShah -- thank you! I changed it and the status went back to `200` but NULL on the result data still :/

Comment: Also, can you please check whether these values are getting set:                                  
    var owed = $("#dpoOwed").val();
    var int = $('#dpoInterest').val();
    var pymt = $('#dpoPayment').val();?

Comment: @ManashreeShah -- checked all values on the JS side before the call and at the PHP side and everything is set as it needs to be. The Network in browser even shows the proper fields being passed.

Comment: is `int` a js keyword /reserved word? `var int = $('#dpoInterest').val();`

Comment: Before returning json object, try setting header $this->request->setHeader('Accept', 'application/json') in php function before the return statement;

Comment: @KenLee -- Good thought! I changed it just in case, but found out my calculations in my PHP script were all wonky; simple fix and re-apply of the algorithm sorted everything out!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE::**

Apparently my math was indeed wrong and was returning a `NAN` via the AJAX call. Once I found this out, I altered my algorithm and the return value came back as needed, and displaying wonderfully!

Always math...

In case anyone is dealing with the similar (*calculating remaining months on loan*), I passed the `string` values via AJAX and handled them all in PHP script, but in a different way:

**New Script Code:**

```
public function calculateLoanPayoff()
{
    $response = array();
    
    $owed = $this->request->getVar('owed');
    $interest = $this->request->getVar('interest');
    $payments = $this->request->getVar('payments');
    
    $interest = ($interest / 100);
    $half_a = -(1 - $interest * $owed / $payments);
    $half_b = (1 + $interest);
    
    // Numner of Payments = (-log(1 - interest * remaining / payments)) / log(1 + interest)
    $months_left = log($half_a) / log($half_b);
    
    $response['months_min'] = ceil($months_left);
    // OTHER VALUES WILL BE ADDED TO THE RESPONSE ARRAY AFTER I NAIL THIS THING
    
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

Thanks for everyone's suggestions and assistance!